# discord.py keyword error while creating a dropdown menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

So I was creating a command to send a drop down menu with some names and when using the keyword `discord.SelectMenu` I am getting an error in its keyword `custom_id`
Here's the code

```
@tree.command(name="troops", description="shows list of troops")
async def troops(interaction):
  mydb.execute("SELECT name FROM troops")
  result = mydb.fetchall()
  options = [discord.SelectOption(label=row[0], value=row[0]) for row in result]

  menu = discord.SelectMenu(custom_id= "troop_menu", placeholder="select a troop", options=options)
  row = discord.ActionRow(menu)
  await interaction.response.send_message("Select a troop:", components=[row])
```

While the error I am getting is

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'troops' raised an exception: TypeError: SelectMenu.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'custom_id'
```

additionaly I am also getting an error saying `Expected 1 more positional argumen` on the `custom_id = "troop_menu"`

Comment: You are using the wrong class, use [`discord.ui.Select`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=selectmenu#discord.ui.Select) instead.